# When do PyBind11 class members get copied from C++ to Python?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

When one creates bindings for C++ class members using PyBind11, when exactly does the member get copied over to Python? Is it when the object is referenced in Python, or when the object member is referenced?

Consider this simple example:

```cpp
// C++
class MyClass
{
  public:
    Eigen::MatrixXd bigMatrix;
}

MyClass createBigMatrix();  // implementation creates a big matrix

PYBIND11_MODULE(wrapper, m)
{

    py::class_<MyClass>(m, "MyClass")
        .def_readonly("bigMatrix", &MyClass::bigMatrix)
        ;

    m.def("createBigMatrix", &createBigMatrix);
}
```

```py
# Python

import wrapper
x = wrapper.createBigImage();  # <-- does MyClass::bigImage get copied from C++ to Python here?
print(x.bigImage);             # <-- or does it get copied here?
```

In other words, is it safe to bind members that may never be referenced/used in Python? Or is it best not to because they will be copied regardless, using valuable compute time and memory?

Comment: In this case there isn't any copying done at all. First line gives you a proxy object referencing the `MyClass` instance. The second call gives you a numpy array observing the data buffer owned by the `MatrixXd` instance. (but if a copy were to happen, it would be on property access -- it's basically a function call behind a bit of syntactic sugar)

Comment: Thank you @DanMašek, that answers my question!

Comment: And I didn't realize that when classes like `Eigen::MatrixXd` are casted to numpy arrays, the array only observes the data buffers and doesn't needlessly copy them. Makes sense!

Comment: @DanMašek One question regarding your comment "it's basically a function call behind a bit of syntactic sugar" -- if property access is a function call that creates a numpy array instance, will a new numpy array be created every time the property is accessed? Or it creates a numpy array on the first property access that is referenced on every subsequent property access?

Comment: Pretty sure it creates a new one every time. (Haven't scrutinized the code to be 100% certain, but I can see myriad ways how any other sort of behaviour could cause trouble).

Comment: @DanMašek if it creates a new numpy array instance on every property access, then   `x.bigImage == x.bigImage` would be `False` in Python correct? Doesn't this seem a bit odd?

Comment: The result of that expression wouldn't be `False`. It would do a per-element comparison and return an array of all `True`s of the same shape. (The `==` operator doesn't mean "are both the same object")

Comment: @DanMašek Apologies, I meant to say `x.bigImage is x.bigImage` would be `False`. Which seems weird, no?

Comment: OK, true. You should be easily able to verify that experimentally. From my perspective, that's not something I'd really expect to be true. You could probably achieve something like that if it was really desired, but it seems to go way past what pybind and similar libraries are meant to achieve.